# How to get AlertDialog working in a generic class rather than Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use AlertDialog in a simple java class which is not an Activity. I do not have an Activity.

I am trying to initialize it by:

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
```

and I think that the issue is visible that I am using `Context` instead of getApplicationContext or CurrentActivity.

I am working with a class which extends an AsyncTask but I cannot get AlertDialog working as it requires something else instead of simply writing context.

I generated the context by this code:

```
Context context;
ClassConstructor (Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}
```

This is how I acquired the context.

I am following a PHP/SQL-Android tutorial and caught up with this issue. I think that I missed something but I can't catch up with it anymore so can anyone provide a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.show()` on the dialog. You don't need an activity context to show a dialog. You do need to mark the dialog as a system alert dialog,

```
public class AlertDialogService extends Service {
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTitle("Test Alert").setMessage("This is a test.");
    Dialog d = b.create();
    d.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    d.show();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Note that your app must have the permission,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

An alternative is to use a dialog-themed activity, and use `Context.startActivity()` to show it.

Comment: I am calling it by .show() but when I call it. It becomes active and throws error. Please show me a detailed way to use Context.startActivity(). I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you are going to report errors here, and hope to get help with them, INCLUDE SOME, OR ANY DETAIL AT ALL ABOUT THE NATURE OF THE ERROR.

Comment: Also, start by googling for "dialog themed activity". If you don't find what you want, ask another question with details of what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify the dialog `type` as a `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` you MUST use an instance of an Activity `Context` to display an `AlertDialog`.  If you try to use an `ApplicationContext` you will get a `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException` error.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159345/2387695

Comment: Yes. This is the exception it is throwing.

Comment: Right.  So as long as you pass an instance of an `ActivityContext` to your plain on Java class this will work fine.  In other words pass the result of `getContext` in the containing activity into your POJO class.  Just remember anytime you're dealing with the UI like Fragments and AlertDialogs you will always need to use the context from the Activity.

Comment: @Travis this is not correct. As long as the dialog is marked as s system dialog it works fine.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman Interesting.  That's a good tip I wasn't aware.  Cool so provided you set type on the dialog window as:  `alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);` and add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` should be good to go.